# Regarding counting the total of different keys

Tags: java

I have a Map  which stores script No. and patient Id in map the script No. is key sine it is always unique ,as shown below

```
Map m = new LinkedHashMap();
m.put ("123", "23"); 
m.put ("323", "23");
m.put ("153", "23");
m.put ("623", "23");
m.put ("125", "23");
m.put ("122", "24");
m.put ("167", "24");
m.put ("173", "24");
m.put ("113", "25");
```

Now my query is is that I need to find out the that how many scripts are there associated with patient Id 23

as we can see above total 5 different scripts are there with patient Id 23 , so I need to calculate total different scripts 
and scripts No.  also associacated with patient Id 23 that is 123,323,153,623,125

I have shown the value as Example but in my situation dynamic values will populate in Map so please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should use generics, they're much easier to work with.

Now all you have to do is go through each key and see if the associated value is what you're looking for:

```
Map<String, String> m = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
...

List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String str: m.keySet()) {
    if(m.get(str).equals("23")) {
        keys.add(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot also it gives an compile time error under the line for(String str: m.keySet()) saying that cannot convert object type to string please advise

Comment: @user1944559: You need to make your map generic like in the first line of code.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need a map in the other direction, that maps patient id to count.  Every time you insert a new record, `get` the entry for that patient, and increment it.

Comment: please post the code a little bit as I have done to understand fully

Comment: You have understood my problem but please post the code ,Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 1):

If `LinkedHashMap` is the only data structure you have, the only way to do this is by iterating over it, and comparing every patient id to `23`.

If for some reason this is unsatisfactory, you could build an auxiliary data structure. However, it's hard to make specific recommendations in this direction without knowing more about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Either iterate through your `Map` or create a `Map` where the 'Patient Id' is the key and the value is a list of 'script No's.

```
    //Field to store the data in:
    Map<PatientId, List<ScriptId>> partientScriptMap = new HashMap<PatientId, 

    // method to add data
    void add(PatientId p, ScriptId s) {
        List<ScriptId> scriptIds = partientScriptMap.get(p);
        if (null == p) {
            scriptIds = new ArrayList<ScriptId>();
        }
        scriptIds.add(s);
        partientScriptMap.put(p, scriptIds);
   }

   // get all ScriptIds related to a PationId 
   List<ScriptId> getScriptIds(PatientId p) {
        return partientScriptMap.get(p);
   }
```

Is your ScriptIds and PatientIds are all Strings, replace them in the above code by `String`
and than you would use it like this:

```
    add("123", "23"); 
    add("323", "23");
    add("153", "23");
    add("623", "23");
    add("125", "23");
    add("122", "24");
    add("167", "24");
    add("173", "24");
    add("113", "25");


    System.out.println("scriptIds for 24: "+getScriptIds("24");
```

Comment: but if the same patiend Id comes again then it will overide the previous one

Comment: Therefore the List as values. If there is already an entry for the patiend Id, simply add the new 'script No' to the list

Comment: please could you post a code so that I can understand fully this is a humble request Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i ++) {
    if (m.get(i) == 23) count ++;
}
```

Just loop through and check each result against 23.

Comment: here 23 value was example but in real time what the value will be even I wont be knowing