# Regarding calculating the total of keys

Tags: java

Please don't consider this question as duplicate although I have a similar question earlier but this time it is different..

```
Map <String, String>m = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
m.put ("123", "23"); 
m.put ("323", "23");
m.put ("153", "23");
m.put ("623", "23");
m.put ("125", "23");
m.put ("122", "24");
m.put ("167", "24");
m.put ("173", "24");
m.put ("113", "25");
```

I need to find out the count of keys associated with patient Id 23 here as shown above 5 keys are associated , I have followed the below approach

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String str: m.keySet())
        {
            if(m.get(str).equals("23")) {
                keys.add(str);
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }
```

Please advise is there any other approach also which is more efficient like making comprator or anything else .

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242951/regarding-counting-the-total-of-different-keys

Comment: You say that this question is different to your previous one, but I fail to see how it is different.

Comment: Do your keys have to be String? Can they be Integer instead?

Comment: @MrSmith42 I suspect OP want to add the numbers in the keys together.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: In the other question OP wanted a list, now the size of the list. That is no real new question.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the map using Map.entrySet() and check if there is a match increment the count.

Its really unclear if you want the count or the sum of the keys:

If you want just the count:

```
Map<String, String>m = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        int count=0;
        for(Map.Entry<String,String> en: m.entrySet()){
            if(en.getValue().equals("23")){
                count++;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(count);
```

If you want sum:

```
Map<String, String>m = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        int sum=0;
        for(Map.Entry<String,String> en: m.entrySet()){
            if(en.getValue().equals("23")){
                sum+=Integer.parseInt(en.getKey());
            }

        }
        System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: @PeterLawrey thanks, but lol,,, i just edited it, i think OP wants the count, not the sum .. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String str: m.values())
        {
            if(m.equals("23")) {
                keys.add(str);

            }
        }
```

You are avoiding hash lookups. Also, if you just need the count; then

```
int count = 0;
for(String str: m.values())
            {
                if(m.equals("23")) {
                    count++
                }
            }
return count;
```